# Remove product with their images

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

Today I remove some product in my magento site. But when I check my media directory I see there images are exist. Now I need when I remove any product then remove all images which assign with that product.

Comment: Unfortunately magento doesn't natively support this. So would you be comfortable running scripts separately that remove the unused images?

Answer (score 1):

There is a free extension for deleting the images that are not in use.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/image-clean.html

Comment: It's nice but I need custom